# nginx can’t open a file inside `/tmp`

Tags: nginx

I’m trying to automate Let’s Encrypt certificate renewal process. So I’m trying to use the webroot authentication method. But I’ve hit a stumbling block. In trying to isolate what’s going wrong this is what I’ve done.

In my site’s config I’ve added a location block for the acme challenge:

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    default_type "text/plain";
    alias /tmp/letsencrypt;
}
```

The diea being the letsencrypt script will use `/tmp/lestencrypt` to store the necessary files. However, to test this out I’ve created the subfolder `letsencrypt` and chmoded it to 777. I then created a file called `test` with the content “testing” and chmoded that to 777.

Now if I attempt to access `domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test` I get a 404 response. Looking at my error log I see the line:

```
2015/12/11 17:38:06 [error] 26593#0: *11 open() "/tmp/letsencrypt/test" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: domain.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/test HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com"
```

I know that file exists, and it should be readable by anyone, for now I’ve set the permissions to 777. So why can’t nginx find it?

Comment: Which version of nginx? On which distribution?

Comment: nginx/1.9.9 self-compiled on Debian 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled letsencrypt, this might be your problem. In your description you wrote 'leSTencrypt' and in the log its 'leTSencrypt'.

You can also check this one [nginx unix domain socket error](https://serverfault.com/questions/463993/nginx-unix-domain-socket-error/464025#464025)
Looks like some distros use separate /tmp directory for each service for security reasons. Try putting your directory in different place and see if it will work.
You can make another 'tmp' with same permissions, for example

  `mkdir /tmpnew
  chmod 1777 /tmpnew`

and use that one to see what happens.

Another reason I can think of is your nginx running in chrooted environment.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether this answers the question or not. Did you in fact test whether `alias /tmp/whatever` can be made to work in nginx when the file name is spelled correctly?

Comment: Yeah sorry, that typo was only in the question. The configs are typed correctly.

Comment: Using a different folder to /tmp has fixed this error.

Comment: But you cant make another folder behave like tmp : deleteing files automaticcly